# Do I have a chance of getting SB-1 approved having my mother severe illness as a reason?

Tags: usa, greencard, sb-1

I am a Pakistani citizen and I went to US in 2016 and stayed about 10 months in total and also got a Green Card that still has expiry date of 2023, and also have a US driver license.

I stayed in US only 10 months in total and then had to come back to Pakistan (and I never returned) for health issues of my mother, she passed away just 1 year ago.

I was a Government servant and took retirement before I went to USA, when I came back to Pakistan, till date, I never took any job.

I have relatives in US too whom I talk to regularly.

How many chances are there to get a visa once again if I apply for Returning Resident (SB-1) immigrant visa?

Or what are other possible ways I can go back to US and become resident again?

Answer (score 5):

Your [previous question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/23781/can-i-still-enter-in-us-with-my-green-card-after-i-left-us-6-years-ago?rq=1) described your situation as leaving the US after 4 months and not 10, and caring for your grandmother and not mother. Also, you previously said that she passed away more than a year ago and you're only considering returning to the US now.

Had I been a VO, I'd consider denying your application just because of those discrepancies in the story. Obviously the VO won't be reading your questions here, and your application will be supported by documents, but still - if what the document prove is not what you claim you'll have a problem for sure.

Other than that - returning just after 4 months to care for a relative, and then waiting got a year after the relative's passing show very few ties to the US and that you've never really been a resident in the US other than by status. I'd say your chances are not high.

I'd suggest discussing this with a US immigration attorney.

Comment: previous question, I was referring to myself, and this question is on behalf of my father ... my father was sponsored by his sister.
My father have all documents to show his mother illness and her death, and also proofs of ties with relatives in US

Comment: whatever written in previous question is true, and that is my case, whatever written in this question is true, this is my father's case, I am just finding advice if any of us have some chance. Over past few years, the appointments for SB-1 remained closed due to COVID, so we couldnt take appointment

Comment: @usa even if we disregard the discrepancies in the stories, the points made in this answer's third paragraph stand, and they do suggest that your father's case for an SB-1 is borderline at best.  The best chance of success is probably to seek the advice of someone who has some experience with actual SB-1 applications and therefore understands how various factors affect the chances of success -- in other words, an experienced US immigration lawyer.  Such a person might be able to identify facts that your father would want to stress in his application.